# How can i implement this optimization algorithm at n-dimentional using R?

Tags: r

Within R i implemented the well-known gradient descent algorithm :

```
    grad_descent<-function(iter = 100, alpha = 0.001 ){
  
  # define the objective function f(x) 
  # iter is the number of itérations to try 
  # alpha is the step parameter 
  
  
  objFun = function (x,y) return(x^2+y^2)  #sphere function / objective function 
  
  # define the gradient of f(x) 
  
  # Note we don't split up the gradient

  
  
  
  gradient <- function(x , y) {
    
    
    result <- c(2*x,2*y)     # vector of gradient / partial dérivatives
    
    return(result)
  }
  
  init = c(1,1)     #initial point search
  
  
  x <- init[1]
  y <- init[2]
  # create a vector to contain all xs for all steps
  x.All = numeric(iter)
  y.All = numeric(iter)
  
  # gradient descent method to find the minimum
  for(i in seq_len(iter)){
    # Guard against NaNs
    tmp <- c(x,y) - alpha * gradient(x,y)
    if ( !is.nan(suppressWarnings(objFun(tmp[1], tmp[2]))) ) {
      x <- tmp[1]
      y <- tmp[2]
    }
    x.All[i] = x
    y.All[i] = y
    
    
    print(c(i, x,y, objFun(x,y)))    # we print the current itération with corresponding objective function value
  }
  
  # print result and plot all xs for every iteration
  print(paste("The minimum of f(x) is ", objFun(x,y), " at position x = ", x, sep = ""))
  plot(x.All, type = "l")  
  
  print(paste("The minimum of f(x) is ", objFun(x ,y), " at position y = ", y, sep = ""))
  plot(y.All, type = "l")  
  
}
    
# Example of excecution  
    grad_descent(iter = 100, alpha = 0.01 )
```

The formula of gradient descent algorithm is as follow :

```
X(0) is the starting point gived by the user.
X(t)=X(t-1)-alpa*gradient(X(n-1))
```

where :

- **alpha is the step** and X(t-1) is the vector of the previous obtained optimum.

The problem :

My code works fine in `2d` but it cannot be used for an objective function that has n variables ( n-dimensions ).
Also i need a way such to use `objFun` as argument of the function  `grad_descent` which means something like :

```
grad_descent(objFun,iter = 100, alpha = 0.001)
```

I wish my question is clear.

Thank you a lot for help !

Comment: have you tried using a vector instead of listing each parameter ? As in  `objFun = function (par_vector)`. You can then read each parameter as `x = par_vector[1], ...,`. If you need to call `objFun` from `grad_descent`, define `objFun` outside of `grad_descent`.

Comment: I'm sorry but i found difficulties to do that !

Comment: Yes solved !  Thank you a lot !!

Answer (score 0):

```
objFun = function (x) return(sum(x^2))  #sphere function / objective function  

grad_descent<-function(objFun ,iter = 100, alpha = 0.001 , start_init ){
  
  # define the objective function f(x) 
  # iter is the number of itérations to try 
  # alpha is the step parameter 

  
  # define the gradient of f(x) 
  
  # Note we don't split up the gradient

  
  
  
  gradient <- function(x) {
    
    
    result <- c(2*x)     # vector of gradient / partial dérivatives
    
    return(result)
  }
  
  init = start_init    #initial point search
  
  
  x <- init

  # create a vector to contain all xs for all steps
  x.All = numeric(iter)

  
  # gradient descent method to find the minimum
  for(i in seq_len(iter)){
    # Guard against NaNs
    tmp <- c(x) - alpha * gradient(x)
    if ( !is.nan(suppressWarnings(objFun(tmp))) ) {
      x <- tmp
    }

    
    
    print(c(i, x,objFun(x)))    # we print the current itération with corresponding objective function value
  }
  
  # print result and plot all xs for every iteration
  print(paste("The minimum of f(x) is ", objFun(x), " at position x = ", x, sep = ""))
  plot(x.All, type = "l")  
  
  
}
    
# Example of excecution  
    grad_descent(objFun ,iter = 100, alpha = 0.01,c(1,1,1))
```